# R: Remove rows from data frame based on file name column

Tags: r

I've got a large csv file I'm reading into a data frame which is itself a combination of csv's. The first column in the data frame is the file name. The file name always ends with a 5 digit number and ".csv" 
The number of occurrences of each file name will vary. Ex:

```
Source File
xxx_00001.csv
xxx_00001.csv
xxx_00001.csv
xxx_00001.csv
xxx_00001.csv
xxx_00002.csv
xxx_00002.csv
xxx_00002.csv
xxx_00002.csv
xxx_00003.csv
xxx_00003.csv
xxx_00003.csv
xxx_00003.csv
xxx_00003.csv
xxx_00003.csv
...
```

How would I go about removing the rows associated with the last n occurrences of the file name? (Say, the last 2?) I'd like to end up with:

```
Source File
xxx_00001.csv
xxx_00001.csv
xxx_00001.csv
xxx_00002.csv
xxx_00002.csv
xxx_00003.csv
xxx_00003.csv
xxx_00003.csv
xxx_00003.csv
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
 library(dplyr)
 n_to_remove <- 2
 filtered <- group_by(df, SourceFile) %>% slice(1:(n()-n_to_remove))
```

`group_by` will make sure that the slice operation occurs for each group separately. `n()` is also a function from `dplyr` that will return the number of rows inside the group.
Note that this will fail if the number of rows of one of the CSVs are smaller than `n_to_remove`.

Comment: What's the "%>%" doing here?

Comment: %>% is known as the pipe operator. It takes the left hand side as the first argument to the function of the right hand side. It is used to avoid having calls like `f(g(h(j(x)))`, instead it would be written as `j(x) %>% h %>% g %>% f`. In the snippet above, it is the same as `tmp <- group_by(df, SourceFile); filtered <- slice(tmp, 1:(n()-n_to_remove))`. A thorough explanation can be seen here: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/07/magrittr-simplifying-r-code-with-pipes.html

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
n <- 2
df1[with(df1, !ave(seq_along(Source_File), Source_File, 
             FUN = function(x) x %in% tail(x,n))), , drop=FALSE]
#     Source_File
#1  xxx_00001.csv
#2  xxx_00001.csv
#3  xxx_00001.csv
#6  xxx_00002.csv
#7  xxx_00002.csv
#10 xxx_00003.csv
#11 xxx_00003.csv
#12 xxx_00003.csv
#13 xxx_00003.csv
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, keep.rownames=TRUE)[, head(.SD, -n) ,.(Source_File)][, rn:=NULL][]
#     Source_File
#1: xxx_00001.csv
#2: xxx_00001.csv
#3: xxx_00001.csv
#4: xxx_00002.csv
#5: xxx_00002.csv
#6: xxx_00003.csv
#7: xxx_00003.csv
#8: xxx_00003.csv
#9: xxx_00003.csv
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Source_File = c("xxx_00001.csv", "xxx_00001.csv", 
"xxx_00001.csv", "xxx_00001.csv", "xxx_00001.csv", "xxx_00002.csv", 
"xxx_00002.csv", "xxx_00002.csv", "xxx_00002.csv", "xxx_00003.csv", 
"xxx_00003.csv", "xxx_00003.csv", "xxx_00003.csv", "xxx_00003.csv", 
"xxx_00003.csv")), .Names = "Source_File", class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```